# Pod file error when installing new pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I tried installing a new pod file for my project and keep getting an error in my Terminal. Everything was working fine before I went to add a new pod to my project. Attached are screenshots of my directory, pod file with TextEdit and TextWrangler, as well as the Terminal. I realized I needed Alamofire, instead of AFNetworking. So I deleted AFNetworking out of my profile to replace it with Alamofire. I still get the same error when I had AFNetworking though in the file and just added Alamofire. What do I do?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 1):

Change the `target` name to `Thrill`. So `target 'Thrill' do`.

Update your podfile to this instead:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Thirll' do
    pod 'Stripe', '~> 4.0',
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I think I had to update ruby. I basically reinstalled everything again and created a new pod file, even though there was already a pod file. Thanks guys!